# Disable points scaling in 3D scatter plots in Mayavi

Tags: python, data-visualization, mayavi

The `mayavi` module for Python has a 3D scatter plotting function. By default the size of the points are scaled with the data (as far as I could understand from going through their website). This is what a screencap of my data looks like:

[image: Mayavi Point Scatter]

The colormap indicates the value of each point, so I don't require the size of the point to also scale with the value of the point. Is there any way to disable scaling of size?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `mayavi.mlab.points3d` has the `scale_mode` argument which can be set to `'none'`.

For example:

```
In [23]: t = linspace(0, 4*numpy.pi, 20)

In [24]: x = sin(2*t)

In [25]: y = cos(t)

In [26]: z = cos(2*t)

In [27]: s = 2 + sin(t)

In [28]: mlab.points3d(x, y, z, s, colormap="copper", scale_mode='none')
Out[28]: <mayavi.modules.glyph.Glyph at 0x9fd85f0>
```

Here's a screenshot of the plot:

[image: screenshot]